# Difference between 'trap -⁠- EXIT' and 'trap - EXIT'

Tags: bash, shell, exit, trap

I've noticed that when Bash is called as `sh`, you cannot unset a trap using e.g., `trap -- EXIT`, but when it is called as `bash` you can.

`trap - EXIT` seems to work regardless of how the shell was called.

---

Example output:

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ ls -l /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Mar  9  2016 /bin/sh -> bash
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ sh
sh-4.1$ trap 'echo something' EXIT
sh-4.1$ exit
exit
something
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ sh
sh-4.1$ trap 'echo something' EXIT
sh-4.1$ trap -- EXIT
trap: usage: trap [-lp] [[arg] signal_spec ...]
sh-4.1$ trap - EXIT
sh-4.1$ exit
exit
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ bash
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ trap 'echo something' EXIT
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ exit
exit
something
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ bash
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ trap 'echo something' EXIT
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ trap -- EXIT
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ exit
exit
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ bash
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ trap 'echo something' EXIT
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ trap - EXIT
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ exit
exit
[vagrant@localhost ~]$
```

---

I checked the documentation but I don't see the difference elucidated anywhere.  I *do* see that the single hyphen form is [specified by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_28_17).

Is there any difference in behavior between the two methods of unsetting a trap, other than `--` not working in `sh`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is explained some in the trap(1P) [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/trap.1p.html) and more in the [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/abs-guide.html#DOUBLEDASHREF), which explains that the `--` is a Bash built-in, used to denote the "end of options" for a command. Since scripts using `sh` are designed to be portable between other systems with it, bash behaves as if it were executed with `--posix`, which changes some shell behavior to match the POSIX specification.

When a signal is "trapped", (e.g., `EXIT`), it binds the first argument after the command to the signal, `eval`-ing it when the signal is issued, and ignoring its normal behavior (except for `EXIT`). So when `trap 'echo something' EXIT` is run, then `exit`, the shell will `eval 'echo something'` prior to exiting. This would also work with a different signal, such as `TERM`, which could be bound to, for example, a graceful exit function in a script. When `trap -- EXIT` is run, the `--` is interpreted as an "end of arguments", indicating to `trap` that the signal is to be bound to null (`''`) (since there were no flags prior to or after `--`), indicating to the shell to ignore the signal (however, this doesn't  work with EXIT, but works with other signals). Running `trap -- 'echo something' EXIT`, however, will still `eval 'echo something'` and exit upon `exit`. As per the specification of `trap`, the command `-` by itself indicates that the shell will reset any traps for the signals specified, which is why it works in both `sh` and Bash.

Comment: Interesting.  So it seems that there *is* a difference, if the trap(s) that will be reset by `trap - EXIT` are different from a null trap?

Comment: @Wildcard: Exactly, there is a difference. For illustration see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/nishanths/6f00820e408cb18c361cfe4a1e5b79f6). However I used INT instead of EXIT to make illustration easier.